# Python3 how to change the error bar style

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Anyone can help me, please?
I have two series data x = [...] and y = [...] with a y error: err = [...]. I am trying to plot this curve with y error bar using

```
x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
y = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=err, uplims=True, lolims=True)
```

But the default bar style of python is an arrow. I know in the old version of matlibplot may have solutions. But I cannot find any clue in current matlibplot documentation. Does anyone know how to change that to the straight line? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the `fig, ax` method:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot, caps, bars = ax.errorbar(x, y, yerr=err, uplims=True, lolims=True)
```

Then use the returned tuple `caps`' set_marker method:

```
caps[0].set_marker('_')
caps[1].set_marker('_')
```

If you want to change their size:

```
caps[0].set_markersize(10)
caps[1].set_markersize(10)
```

For example:

```
x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
y = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
err = np.linspace(1,2, 10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot, caps, bars = ax.errorbar(x, y, yerr=err, uplims=True, lolims=True)
caps[0].set_marker('_')
caps[1].set_marker('s')
caps[0].set_markersize(10)
caps[1].set_markersize(5)
```

[image: Example plot]

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Thanks!!